# PL SQL with REGEXP match all items in list

Tags: plsql

Can I test if a REGEXP expression matches all value in a list of values?
I want something like:

```
 where  REGEXP_LIKE(data, ALL(input1,input2))
```

how can I do that?
and I want to test if a REGEXP expression matches any value in a list of values, something like:

```
 where  REGEXP_LIKE(data, ANY(input1,input2))
```

Examples:

```
data = 22251455 , 22247821 , 22958812

input1 = REGEXP("AAA")

input2 = REGEXP("ABB")

where  REGEXP_LIKE(data, ALL(input1,input2))
```

will return only 22251455 because it contains 222 like AAA and 455 like ABB ,
while

```
 where  REGEXP_LIKE(data, ANY(input1,input2))
```

will return 22251455 , 22247821 , 22958812

Comment: Please provide some sample data, and expected output.

Comment: I have a string split by comma in an asp.net mvc 4 project and I converted every sub-string to regex and send the converted string to oracle stored procedure that  convert comma separated string to array and I want to check if item in table matches all items in this array and check if item in table matches any item in this array

Answer (score 0):

For "ANY" you can try by below query .
Below is the example i have table emp with data contained below.

```
 empno  empname
    110 raag
    111 radd
    102 sam
    104 leo
    105 ram
    102 sam
    103 mam
```

query:-

```
select * from emp where regexp_like(lower(ename), '^(radd|leo|sam)');
```

out put:-

```
empno empname
111 radd
102 sam
104 leo
102 sam
```